# "Live" graph d3.js with simulated data

Tags: d3.js

I have created a simple line graph with data from a mySQL database using PHP to return the data in JSON format.

https://gist.github.com/5fc4cd5f41a6ddf2df23

I would like to simulate "live" updating something similar to this example, but less complicated: 
http://bl.ocks.org/2657838

I've been searching for examples on how to achieve this simply as new to D3 - to no avail.

I've looked at Mike Bostock's http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/ path transitions, but not sure how to implement this using json data.

Can anyone help with either an example or some direction on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Doing that kind of line transformations is tricky in SVG because moving large number of *points* just a little and rerendering the complete line can hurt performance.

For the case when interactivity with each data point is not paramount and the time series can grow to contain arbitrary number of points, consider using [Cubism](http://square.github.com/cubism/). It is a library based on d3 but meant specially for visualizing time-series data efficiently. To prevent rerendings of SVG, it draws the points on a canvas, allowing for cheap pixel by pixel transitions as new data arrives.

Comment: Thank you - does Cubism only allow for time-series horizon charts?  From what I see from the API this seems to be the case - maybe I'm wrong?  I need this layout with a line graph http://bl.ocks.org/2657838

Comment: Yes, only horizon and comparison charts. I think part of the desired layout can be imitated using cubism with some judicious color settings and by choosing appropriate scales but, yes, Cubism was meant as a very specific library. In this case, building your own line graph (as in your example) will allow you greater flexibility.

Comment: Thanks - upon reading more about Cubism it does look like a more efficient option.  There doesn't seem to be that much information or many examples out there about it though. My data is in JSON format - how would I go about implementing a Cubism time series graph using this type of data source?  Any direction or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: upvoted! does this mean the whole translate(x(-1)) is bad for performance

Comment: @PirateApp I'm not sure I follow; did you mean `translate(x+1)` movement on an SVG circle/g/rect, etc.? I do not know how efficient these translations are (they will be browser implementation dependent), though I suspect that canvas renderings are likely to be more efficient. However, in this particular case, updating the `d` attribute of the `path` was less efficient than `translate(x - 1)` and adding a point at the end. Hope that helps.

Comment: so basically is it true that live streaming should be done over canvas given the svg nature of things involving translation and stuff :) you have given me a hint