# Transition line/path to depict "live" data D3

Tags: d3.js

Following on from previous post:

["Live" graph d3.js with simulated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664496/live-graph-d3-js-with-simulated-data).

I am pulling data at 1 minute intervals from database.  The json array is being updated with the new "live" data, but while both x and y axis's are updating the line/path isn't?

https://gist.github.com/Majella/5fc4cd5f41a6ddf2df23

I cannot figure out why this is - can anyone help?

PS - tried adding data.push() and data.shift() to the "SetInterval" function to allow for the new data - doesn't seem to make any difference - and the axis's are being condensed and difficult to read as the new data added.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the axes are getting compressed. This would indicate that your data is continually being added to in the MySQL table, but then when you run your query, you are pulling ***all*** the time values out.

Could I suggest that you include a line in your MySQL query that only pulls out the amount data in the length of time that you want to display.

For instance, if you wanted to display 60 minutes of data only select the last hour worth of results with an appropriate 'WHERE' statement something like this...

```
SELECT dateTimeTaken, reading FROM TestSourceSampleData 
WHERE dateTimeTaken BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND NOW()
GROUP BY dateTimeTaken
```

(The query is untested)

The other thing you might want to try is to use v3 of d3.js (`d3.v3.js` in line 14 of your html file). Which means I think that you'll have to include the error trap in the d3.json line like so;

```
d3.json("getdata.php", function(error, data) {
```

At lines 45 and 131.

Give those ideas a try.

Comment: Thank you.  A new row is being added to the database every minute to simulate "live" data.  When I run the query initially and stringify the array it shows the data currently in the table - when pull the data again at one minute intervals and stringify it - it shows the additional line each time - so it is doing what it is meant to do.  I think I need to push and shift the array at each one minute interval to allow for the new data to stop the compression?  Not sure how to word this though as everything I've tried hasn't worked?

Comment: ...and as axis's are transitioning as expected then must be something small either missing or incorrect in the code that is preventing the line/path from doing the same.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure that I understand the compression part properly, but I'm fairly sure with your original query, that you will get it compressing. I was going to suggest looking at the `.enter()` and `.exit()` commands here http://d3js.org/#enter-exit but I still think that as I understand the problem using a query with a BETWEEN statement should sort the problem. I've still got nothing with regard the line rendering though.

Comment: How about changing your code so that is loads two different JSON files in the two places where you are currently loading the php scripts to eliminate the php as a factor perhaps. Start narrowing down the responsible code. Try http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/update-d3js-data-dynamically-button.html as an example (at the end is a file that does this so that you can compare the transitions.

Comment: Thanks but pulling in the data isn't the problem - the data is as it should be.  I've solved the line transition problem - in the update function instead of selecting ".line" changed to "path.line" and this has done the trick.  I've put data.shift() to remove the oldest/first element in the array after call the data in again and it is working but with console errors.

Comment: For some reason data.shift() only working when first call data again - think that's why getting the errors.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803976/remove-element-in-json-array-as-new-data-added#comment20760095_14803976

Comment: Hmm.. Sorry that's an area i haven't played with.