# Remove element in json array as new data added?

Tags: d3.js

I have a line graph that is being updated every 5 seconds as new data is pulled from a mySQL database.

https://gist.github.com/Majella/5fc4cd5f41a6ddf2df23

How do I remove the first/oldest element from the array each time the data is called to stop the line/path being compressed?

I've tried adding data.shift() in the update function just after the data is called but only works for the first call?

Comment: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/

Comment: I'd already looked at that and still have the same problem - only removing the first/oldest element in the array for the first call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of what lives behind getdata.php, but I assume it's returning progressively more data points each time, thus removing only the first one still lives you with a larger data set than you want. So you have a couple choices:

1. Change the server-side of getdata.php to return only the latest x data points (or maybe add a querystring parameter for how many points/minutes/whatever to retrieve)
2. Change the client-side in updateData to check the length of the array and .slice off the elements starting at lengthYouWant minus lengthYouReceived (assuming the data is already sorted correctly)

Comment: Thanks - as you can see from the link above - getdata.php is retrieving the last 10 mins worth of data.  I'll try your second suggestion:)